# Why is this answer downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/24372/13147

It answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote Tim Post,

### [The answer was down voted because I lost my keys.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)

Seriously, people's voting habits on Stack Exchange can be *very* random. In this case, I suspect that people downvoted because the image was very large, perhaps obtrusive, and definitely contained much more than just the game.

Also, posts with downvotes usually tend to only attract more donwvotes. Psychologically, people appear to shy away from challenging the established majority of - *gasp* - one person!

Don't take it personally. If there is feedback given, consider implementing it. If there isn't, then A. You are knowingly spamming the site and no one needs to tell you that **(*You* aren't - that comment was for future users with similar questions)** or B. The downvoting was likely random stuff. Consider the amount of effort you put into the post. If you put it together carelessly, I suggest editing the post and/or give more effort in the future. **If, however, you put the post together thoughtfully and received no feedback, then...**

### Don't worry about it.

Stuff (like random downvotes) happen.

---

By the way, I edited your answer to improve the formatting. I also upvoted your answer (*after* the edit).

Comment: But FOUR downvotes?

Comment: It even got deleted. My answer that actually answers the question got deleted.

Comment: Ok, I posted it afresh with your edits. Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

I downvoted your answer because it comes across as braggadocio.  You speak of your "brilliant" play and give a double exclam to Kc4 (it should be Kf6, but that's another story) as if it is some incredibly difficult move to find when it is actually pretty easy.

For what it's worth, I saw Kf6 after looking at the position for a few seconds and I am sure others who have studied king and pawn endgames and have experience with them would as well.

Comment: OK. It sounded to me like he was bragging on the GMs. To each his own! Have a good day.

Comment: @Brandon_J Judging by his comments in the other answers here, it seems unlikely.

Comment: Reuben Fine gave it two exclamation marks - not me. Read the book. Are you questioning that a GM gave it two exclamation marks?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't vote either way, but perhaps some voters were rubbed the wrong way by your immodesty.

Comment: Kosteniuk talks like this. Also, your playing small does not serve the world. There is nothing enlightened about shrinking so that other people won't feel insecure around you.

Comment: Usain Bolt talks like that, too. The difference is they are world champions and you are not. :-) But don't tell _me_, I don't care; like I said, I didn't vote.

Comment: Actually, all winners talk like that.

Comment: @JossieCalderon in hindsight, it does appear that immodesty was the reason for the downvotes. I would request that you change the accepted answer to Qudit or itub's answer, since mine doesn't exactly answer the question.